# ¿Cómo se puede 'leer' o interpretar facilmente la forma reducida del for?

Tags: python

Yo usualmente he usado la estructura del for básica como puede ser :

```
movil = "xiaomi"
for letra in xiaomi:
   print(letra)
```

Pero ahora me han enseñado una forma nueva, la cual es mas reducida:

```
filtradas = [(e, s) for e, s in audiencias if e in ediciones]
```

(este ejemplo no tiene nada que ver con el anterior)
Alguien podría explicarme como puedo interpretar esto?

Comment: Tienes un ciclo con condición es decir solo los que cumplen la condición pasaran por el ciclo

Answer (score 6):

Lo que llamas "ciclo for reducido" se llama oficialmente [comprensión de listas](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/datastructures.html#comprension-de-listas) (en inglés, *list comprehensions*).

En el enlace que te acabo de poner tienes todos los detalles sobre cómo funcionan, pero básicamente sirven para evaluar una expresión en bucle, e ir recopilando el valor de esa expresión en cada iteración del bucle.

La forma general es:

```
resultado = [ expresion for variable in iterable if condicion ]
```

y equivale a:

```
resultado = []
for variable in iterable:
   if condicion:
      resultado.append(expresion)
```

En tu ejemplo:

```
[(e, s) for e, s in audiencias if e in ediciones]
```

La expresión es `(e, s)`. Estas variables pueden existir previamente fuera de la comprensión, pero lo habitual es que sean las variables cuyos nombres aparecen después del `for`.

En tu caso, después del `for`, en lugar de un nombre de variable (que es lo habitual) tenemos dos. En realidad es porque se está usando un desempaquetado implícito de tuplas. Se entiende que cada iteración del `for` producirá una tupla de dos elementos, y al poner dos nombres de variables separados por comas, cada una de estas variables recibirá un elemento de la tupla. Al final pongo otra forma de hacerlo sin este desempaquetado implícito.

Después viene la palabra `in`, tras la cual debe aparecer un iterable. En tu caso por tanto el iterable será `audiencias`. Un iterable es algo sobre lo que puedes iterar y que te da un dato nuevo en cada iteración (dicho de otra forma, algo que puedes poner tras un `for X in ...`). En este caso, se deduce que dentro del iterable hay tuplas de dos elementos y que al iterar van saliendo esas tuplas que se asignan a las variables `e, s`.

Finalmente puede aparecer un `if` y una condición (esa parte es opcional). En la condición puede aparecer cualquiera de las variables que tengas en tu programa, así como las propias variables que contienen cada iteración dentro de la comprensíon. En este caso la condición es `e in ediciones`, siendo `e` el primer elemento de la tupla de esta iteración, y `ediciones` algún tipo de colección.

Si la condición es falsa, esa iteración "se salta". Si es cierta, se evalúa la expresión que aparece al principio (en este caso `(e,s)` y se guarda el resultado en la lista que se está construyendo. Si no existe la parte de la condición, no se salta ningún elemento.

Toda esa expresión equivale a este otro bucle "normal":

```
filtradas = []
for e, s in audiencias:
    if e in ediciones:
        filtradas.append((e,s))
```

Si el desempaquetado implícito de tuplas en `e, s` te confunde, quizás entiendas mejor esta otra sintaxis, en la que no la desempaqueto, y me veo entonces forzado a usar `datos[0]` en lugar de `e` para acceder al primer elemento de esa tupla:

```
filtradas = [ datos for datos in audiencias if datos[0] in ediciones ]
```

Habría más cosas que contar, como que por ejemplo puedes usar una sintaxis casi igual pero poniendo paréntesis alrededor en lugar de corchetes, y entonces tendrías lo que se llama una "expresión generadora", y que hay otra sintaxis muy similar para generar diccionarios por comprensión, y que puedes incluso tener bucles `for` anidados, pero personalmente los encuentro difíciles de leer.

Comment: Para complementar al que preguntó, Python es un lenguaje extremadamente versátil a la hora de escribir instrucciones. En una sola línea se pueden meter muchas instrucciones y el lenguaje permite operaciones de muy alto nivel imposible de hacer en varios otros lenguajes, como iterar y hacer comparaciones dentro de estructuras de datos. Personalmente he visto casos que yo he resuelto en 20 líneas y alguien aparece con un flamante "1 línea" que hace lo mismo y a veces hasta mejor. No necesariamente una linea es más eficiente que varias, siempre y cuando se siga la sintaxis correcta del lenguaje.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me ha sido de gran ayuda

Comment: Buenas, si la respuesta te sirve debes darle al "visto" verde al lado de su respuesta y si quieres darle un voto positivo, pero no crear una respuesta nueva. Además así te ganarás unos puntos extra y subirás de rango ;)